# Why does my RegExp return false with proper number of characters?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

```
$gi = filter_var(filter_var($_POST['group_id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
        FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array(
           "options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z0-9_](?=[^\s]+$).{5,20}$/")));
```

That is the code I'm using.  This is a PHP & MySQL application.  The problem is that it is returning FALSE with anything 5 characters or shorter.  If I change the '5' to a '6', then anything 6 characters or shorter returns FALSE.  Why is this?

Also, the following code behaves the same:

```
$gi = filter_var($_POST['group_id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
        array("options"=>array(
           "regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z0-9_](?=[^\s]+$).{5,20}$/")));
```

I'm under the impression that my regexp is 1) limiting entries to letters, numbers, and underscores, 2) prohibiting whitespace, and 3) requiring atleast 5 characters and setting a maximum of 20 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_](?=[^\s]+$).{5,20}
```

is matching 5 characters, but only after it matches 1 character within `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, and then on to the 5 characters. So at minimum you need a 6 character string to match.

Based on your last paragraph, something like the following is more to what you're looking for:

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z_]{5,20}$/
```

*EDIT: Corrected thanks to @Allan, not quite in to the cognitive thinking pattern yet, coffee deprivation. ;-)*

Comment: Isnt `^` the negation operator? AFAIK `^\w` is equal to `\W`

Comment: The minimum length is six, not seven.  `(?=[^\s]+$)` is a lookahead, so it doesn't consume any characters.

Comment: Thanks, Brad.  One more minor question that I haven't been able to work out.  How would I modify that regex to prohibit certain words?  eg. qwerty, or profanities?

Comment: I don't know of a way in RegEx without using a backreference. Something similar to `(?:(!qwerty)|(!admin)|...)` etc. It may just make sense to create a list of "unacceptable" words and use `if (!in_array($word,$unacceptable)) { ... }` instead of embedding it in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
/.{5,20}/
```

This piece of RegEx is responsible as you are asking the engine to match AT LEAST 5 characters (Any characters) and 20 characters if max. Fix that piece accordingly.

Hope it helps :)

EDIT: Sorry, didnt read the last part of the question.

1) Wrong. The ^ operator negates whatever is in front, so the first char CAN NOT be any letter, any number nor underscore [Replace that with `/^[\w_]/` if you really want that overkill filtering]
2) Right. There cannot be whitespaces before that end of line.
3) Pretty much whats above the EDIT ;)

For more regex info go to http://regular-expressions.info